# Is the set of functions from $X$ to $\Bbb C$ with sup norm Banach?

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a nonempty set.

Define $F(X)= \{f:X\longrightarrow \Bbb C , f\text{ is a function}\}$ and $\|f\|=\sup|f|$. Then $(F(X),\|.\|)$ is a Banach space? If not why?

Comment: It's not even a normed space. Maybe you imply that $F$ consists of $f$ such that $||f|| < \infty$?

Comment: It is true if $X$ is finite. However, if $X$ is not finite, it will not be a Banach space (not even a normed space), see the hint of Robert Israel.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What if $f$ is unbounded?

Answer (score 1):

As stated, $\lVert f\rVert$ could be infinite, so it's not even a norm. What is true is that if $V$ is a Banach space (either real or complex), and $X$ a non-empty set, then the
set of bounded functions
\begin{align}
B(X,V):= \{f:X\to V| \, \, \text{$f$ a function with $\lVert f\rVert_{\infty}:=\sup_{x\in X}\lVert f(x)\rVert_V < \infty$}\}
\end{align}
is a Banach space with the norm $\lVert \cdot\rVert_{\infty}$. In particular you can take $V=\Bbb{C}$ to get a complex Banach space $B(X,\Bbb{C})$.